# Como puedo correr unas pruebas e2e en vue3, con docker

Tags: vue.js, docker

Muy buenas a todo quien lea este issus.
actualmente estoy haciendo pruebas de en vue, pero como estoy desarrollando en un entorno dockerisado, quisiera saber si saben como es posible que pueda hacer las pruebas desde docoker, intente agregar al apckage.json  `"test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e  --headless",` pero no me funcionó
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]